# I can't make changes to a Django queryset then run filters on changed data

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I tried putting the queryset in a list but then the list object has no method exclude(). I need to find all the start_date's that are in the last month if they have and end_date that is after 12 then I want to change the start_date's month to 1 so that when I exclude dates before 1-1-nextyear and 1-31-nextyear I will get back the remained of the dates that lie on the month of 1.

```
def next_month_request(request, id, currentyear, currentmonth):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if int(request.GET.get('currentmonth')) == 12:
            nextyear = int(request.GET.get('currentyear')) + 1
            qs = ContractorSchedule.objects.filter(firstname_id=int(request.GET.get('id')))
            queryset = []
            for i in qs: 
                if i.start_date.month == 12 and i.end_date.month == 1:
                    h,m =  i.start_date.hour, i.start_date.minute
                    i.start_date = last_day_of_month(i.start_date) +     datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)+ datetime.timedelta(hours=h) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=m)
                    queryset.append(i)
            queryset[0] = queryset[0].exclude(
                                        start_date__lt=last_day_of_month(                                      datetime.datetime(int(request.GET.get('currentyear')),                                           int(request.GET.get('currentmonth')),1)
                                        )).exclude(                                        start_date__gt=datetime.datetime(nextyear,1,31,23,59,59))
            if queryset.exists():
                htmlcalendar = next_last_month_contractor_calendar(queryset)
            else:
                htmlcalendar = LocaleHTMLCalendar().formatmonth(nextyear,1)
```

Comment: But you can't store dates in database with month>12, can you?

Comment: You code is missing something after the second `exclude`. Could be helpful if you post your model.